# Where to find the DatastoreViewerServlet - GAE?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, guice

My application JAX-RS/Guice mappings overrides the GAE SDK admin mappings. So I need to explicitly "serve" it through the Guice serve module

```
    serve("_ah/admin/datastore*").with(DatastoreViewerServlet.class); // does not work
    serve("/appstats/*").with(AppstatsServlet.class); // works!
```

The problem I face is that I can't find this `DatastoreViewerServlet` in the GAE SDK class path. I'm GAE SDK version 1.7.5

Tried this:

```
com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.DatastoreViewerServlet
```

but its not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The servlet is in the following jar under your GAE SDK folder.

> lib/shared/appengine-local-runtime-shared.jar

Copying the jar to your WEB-INF/lib and adding it to your build-path will at least allow you to reference it.  As for whether it works as intended after that I hope that you are lucky.